# Rendering Web Components in Svelte

Tags: svelte, web-component, sveltekit, svelte-component

I'm trying to add a custom (Svelte) web component, as documented [here](https://svelte.dev/docs#run-time-custom-element-api) to a `contenteditable` div as HTML.  For some reason, it's not rendering properly.

I've put together a [REPL here](https://svelte.dev/repl/91e415b296284054a83f38e347cf5f54?version=3.57.0).  If you type in anything worth the word "test" in the sentence, "test" should become part of the web component that's defined in `Token.svelte`, and highlighted red.  Instead, it just renders the string to the DOM:

`<source-token type="ambiguity">test</source-token>`

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong/missing?

Comment: There's a warning in the Repl *The 'tag' option is used when generating a custom element. Did you forget the 'customElement: true' compile option?* The project needs to be configured to both compile the normal components plus a webcomponent which is used

Comment: Right - I checked the box for custom components in the REPL compiler, it still doesn’t seem to work.

Comment: Here's an article on the subject https://www.thisdot.co/blog/web-components-with-svelte#:~:text=together%20or%20not.-,%F0%9F%94%97,-Working%20with%20regular (I can't say if that's a good solution)